# Show or list value of a data cell by column name

Tags: c#, database, ole

```
.
.
.
OleDbDataReader getme = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while (getme.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(getme.GetString(1));
            }
.
.
.
```

I've used getme.GetString(1) to be show the value of specific cell from the table in a message box. I've opened the database as usual and i don't have datagrid.

How can i use the column name instead of the integer ID, GetString(1) or GetInt32(0) or etc.?

isn't is possible to choose the column with column name instead of numerical value?

I am doing this in C#.NET.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that two ways:

`getMe.GetOrdinal("column_name")` returns the index to use for `GetString` `GetInt32` etc. If you do this, you can save some time by doing it outside the `while` loop.

```
OleDbDataReader getMe = cmd.ExecuteReader();
int index = getMe.GetOrdinal("column_name");
while (getme.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(getMe.GetString(index));
}
```

`OleDbDataReader` (your, `getMe`) defines an indexer. You can use `getMe["column_name"]`, and then simple cast it to the type of object you want:

```
OleDbDataReader getMe = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (getme.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)getMe["column_name"]);
}
```

See [oleDbDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader_members%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getordinal%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Use GetOrdinal Method.